# PDF Not loading anymore on Flex Air Application

Tags: apache-flex

Ever since I updated my Adobe Readed to Version 11, I can't view any PDF on my Flex Air Application anymore. Is there anything i need to do?

- AIR version: 3.6
- OS: Mac OS X
- Flex Builder: 4.6
- Adobe Reader: 11.0.02
- Flex components used: mx:HTML

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with stagewebview?

You have to do something like this:

```
webView = new StageWebView();

webView.loadURL("http://<url>/xxx.pdf");

webView.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 100,this.stage.stageWidth, this.stage.stageHeight);
webView.stage = this.stage;
```

Comment: Yeah. Still doesn't work. As i build the project i get an error that flex cannot load the reader.